# FATAL: role "roelof" does not exist

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I did install postgresql according to the manual.
But as soon as I do rails server I see the above error.

Roelof

Edit 1: the sudo -u postgres createuser roelof did the trick but now when I do rake db:create I see this errror message:

PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database

Answer (score 1):

You can create a role with your name by running a `createuser` command as the postgres **system user**. Run this in a terminal:

```
 sudo -u postgres createuser roelof
```

Comment: thanks, solved one problem and a new problem does arise. see edit 1

Comment: I also found `sudo -u postgres createdb roelof` useful, so I could simply run `psql`

Answer (score 0):

For **PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied to create database**:

Another way to resolve this problem is going to `psql` and type `\du` to list all roles. Make sure your role has the following things:

```
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 ubuntu    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

You might want to use this command `psql=# CREATE ROLE roelof SUPERUSER CREATEDB REPLICATION CREATEROLE LOGIN;` to resolve this problem.

Next, configure your database.yml:

```
username: [insert the username]
```

and if you configured a password, please provide it:

```
host: localhost
password: #######
port: 5437
```

Best wishes.